# Spring Dependency Injection, Scope and Memory Leaks

Tags: spring, memory-leaks, dependency-injection, struts2, scope

In one of our web application (Struts2 + Spring 2.5 + iBatis), we use the following MVC strcuture.

ActionClass <---> ServiceInterface <---> ServiceImplementationClass <---> DAOClass <---> DB

All these java classes are instantiated using Spring. The Service class is injected into the Struts2 Action class using the DI technique. I have questions around the scope attribute used in the spring application context xml.

The following is a sample entry from our Spring applicationcontext.xml.

I would like to understand

a. From concurrency perspective, is it correct to have only the action class as Prototype and rest of the layer classes as Singleton ?

b. From memory leak perspective, is there any guidelines in defining the scope ?

```
    <bean id="commonAction" scope="prototype"
    class="com.xyz.action.CommonAction">
    <property name="commonService" ref="commonService" />
</bean>

<bean id="commonService" class="com.xyz.service.impl.CommonServiceImpl">
    <property name="commonDao" ref="commonDao" />
</bean>

<bean id="commonDao" class="com.xyz.dao.impl.CommonDAOImpl">
    <property name="sqlMapClient" ref="sqlMap" />
</bean>
```

and here is our Struts xml entry

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false"></constant>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
```

Your response to this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The concurrency question can't be answered without knowing more about the implementation of your implementation. Actions are expected to be per-request (i.e., prototype). The thread safety of other classes is up to you--in general, services and DAOs should be written to be thread-safe hence the default "singleton" scope is okay, but they don't *need* to be singletons, it's just typical. Object instantiation is cheap.

I'm not sure what you're asking about from the "memory leak perspective", scope isn't directly related to memory leaks--holding on to references is what normally causes a leak.

Comment: thank you for your response. could you please explain, why is that Actions are expected to be per-request ? Is it because ,the user data from the JSP needs to be uniquely maintained per request ? and if the service injected within action is singleton, does it mean, a single instantiation of service is used across various instances of Action ? and having them as singleton allows us to less use the heap , is that correct ?

Comment: regarding memory leaks, i was wondering since Spring is creating all these objects, how is the lifecyle of it is maintained ? so was thinking if scope could play any role for unclaimed objects due to wrong scope choice.

Comment: regarding thread-safety in other layes (Service & DAOs) where singleton classes are created, i see that no different code/technique is used for thread safety. they (service & dao) have public methods with local variables for operations. Is there anything specific you are mentioning when you mean thread-safety ?